# Monitoring GPU activity

Tags: gpu

I would like to be able to monitor my GPU but not in the way I have found around the internet.

I would like to check what my GPU does when I get an error in a lot of games and the game crashes.

Basically not only monitoring GPU temperature, clock speed, but basically monitoring every single activity of it, and storing it in a log, for me to read later.

Tell me if I wasn't clear enough.

Edit: Windows 10, Nvidia GTX 650 Ti

Comment: It might highly depend on which OS and GPU you have, so please do edit your question to add some specs.

Comment: Edit: Windows 10, Nvidia GTX 650 Ti

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MSI Afterburner](http://www.zombiemodding.com/index.php?topic=12554.0) (`log historyto file`)

[image]

and [GPU-Z](https://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2013/08/01/monitor-your-gpu-on-windows-with-gpu-z-by-techpowerup/) (`log to file`) can log GPU data.

[image]

Comment: That's the thing, I need to monitor actual activites the GPU is doing, as in what is being requested from the GPU, and what it accomplishes.

Comment: this is nearly impossible. You can try WPT/GPUView, but this won't help. Ask the support of the crashing game.

Comment: Which driver version do you use? try this one: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/90500/en-us

Comment: This is the one I currently have, and it still does this.

Comment: Also try older drivers